# Check if image exists at storage with firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

i need your help with one function that i createed to manipulate the images that my users send to my app.

What i need is get the image that the user sent, resize and check if the image was changed to avoid the function to do all again. The examples that i saw change the image name and check if the beggined if the name is equals with the name set, but in my case i need keep the original name of the picture, So, how can i do that? Or exists a better way to solve this problem?
My function code is:

```
  import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

  import * as Storage from '@google-cloud/storage';
  const gcs = new Storage();

  import { tmpdir } from 'os';
  import { join, dirname } from 'path';

  import * as sharp from 'sharp';
  import * as fs from 'fs-extra';

  export const generateThumbs = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async object => {
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
    const filePath = object.name;
    const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
    const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);

    const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'thumbs');
    const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, 'source.png');

    if (!object.contentType.includes('image')) {
      console.log('exiting function');
      return false;
    }

    // 1. Ensure thumbnail dir exists
    await fs.ensureDir(workingDir);

    // 2. Download Source File
    await bucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tmpFilePath
    });

    // 3. Resize the images and define an array of upload promises
    const sizes = [64, 128, 256];

    const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
      const thumbName = `thumb@${size}_${fileName}`;
      const thumbPath = join(workingDir, thumbName);

      // Resize source image
      await sharp(tmpFilePath)
        .resize(size, size)
        .toFile(thumbPath);

      // Upload to GCS
      return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
        destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName)
      });
    });

    // 4. Run the upload operations
    await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    // 5. Cleanup remove the tmp/thumbs from the filesystem
    return fs.remove(workingDir);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to overwrite the original file, and you want to avoid an infinite loop with this function, you could attach [custom metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#custom-metadata) to the file when you upload it back to Cloud Storage.  Then, when the function is invoked again for that file, you can check the [metadata on the incoming ObjectMetadata object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata#metadata) to know when the function should bail out without making any more changes.

Comment: This probably will solve my problem, but i don't know how can i add a custom metadata in my code, can you give me an example?

Comment: There are descriptions and samples on how to use the API in the documentation I linked.  Click through to anything that sounds relevant.  You could probably also find some samples if you perform some searches.